# Match entire list with values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, match

I have a dataframe with a list in one column and want to match all items in this list with a second dataframe. The matched values should then be added (as a list) to a new column in the first dataframe.

```
data = {'froots':  [['apple','banana'], ['apple','strawberry']]
        }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = {'froot':  ['apple','banana','strawberry'],
        'age': [2,3,5]
        }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

DF1

```
index fruits
1     ['apple','banana']
2     ['apple','strawberry']
```

DF2

```
index fruit age
1     apple 2
2     banana 3
3     strawberry 5
```

New DF1

```
index froots                  age
1     ['apple','banana']      [2,3]
2     ['apple','strawberry']  [2,5]
```

I have a simple solution that takes way too long:

```
age = list()
for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    numbers = row.froots
    tmp = df2[['froot','age']].apply(lambda x: x['age'] if x['froot'] in numbers else None, axis=1).dropna().tolist()
    age.append(tmp)
df1['age'] = age
```

Is there maybe a faster solution to this problem?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I would like to believe that this process could be faster within plain python, and then read it back into pandas. you are aggregating items into lists, so no calculations per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lsit comprehension with dictionary created by `df2` and add new values to list if exist in dictionary tested by `if`:

```
d = df2.set_index('froot')['age'].to_dict()

df1['ag1e'] = df1['froots'].apply(lambda x: [d[y] for y in x if y in d])
print (df1)
                froots    ag1e
0      [apple, banana]  [2, 3]
1  [apple, strawberry]  [2, 5]
```